# Update component state from outside React (on server response)

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the process of learning React. At the moment I have several `components` chained as parent-child, communication across them is done easily with callbacks.

I have a **table** (react component) and a small modal ajax **form** (no react). When I receive the **response** (an item) from the server I would like to **add the item to the table.**

My main question is, is it possible to **trigger** a component **state change** from **outside react** (in this case on server response)?

Comment: Sometimes you can get by with just calling render again. render(<Shop />, document.getElementById('shop'))

Answer (score 104, accepted):

> Can you trigger a component state change outside a component?

**Yes.** Heres a simple example

In your react component set up a globally available closure which will update it's state when the function is fired.

```
componentDidMount(){
 globalVar.callback = (data) => {
    // `this` refers to our react component
    this.setState({...});     
  };
}
```

Then when your ajax'd response comes back you can fire the event with the returned data

```
globalVar.callback(data);
```

Or for something more robust, use a [custom event or subscription](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#adding-event-listeners-or-subscriptions)

Comment: Excellent! I got it working saving react object reference on a global var, but it didn't feel right. This way is much cleaner.

Comment: I got the following error: "globalVar is undefined". Do I have to define it first?

Comment: Yes, prior to rendering your component, you would set up the global.

Comment: What is the "callback" function tied to your global variable? Never heard of it?

Comment: @Jarzka it is an arbitrary name. It could be `fooBar` instead of `callback`

Comment: how do you setup the global?

Comment: reactClassComponentInstance.setState(data), is there some way to call the method from another js module outside react context?

Comment: How brilliant. Now I can refactor legacy apps, by replacing it partially with React without need of total rewrite. Thank you !

Comment: @vgoklani    globalVar = this; in component constructor

Answer (score 4):

`component` state best practice is to hold truly internal `state` data, not of interest outside component. If you must change a component from new external data use `props`, just change `props` from outside and the component rerender will react to changes.

Based on new `props` the component may use them on the rerender, or change state as did it in the constructor. The correct place to this task is in `componentWillReceiveProps`, in this method you can change state from new props without get into an eternal loop.

UPDATE: from react 16.3 componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated and getDerivedStateFromProps must be used, with improved detection of bad use cases and side effects. See https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: I wonder if how will this work? The prop value will change outside of react, how will react know if it needs to check for changes and do some rerender?

Comment: props change are in a parent component, and new props, setState or forceUpdate fires on react a refresh cycle over component

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He means to trigger the change outside of react. Not in the parent component. See the accepted answer.

Comment: you are right, I didn't understand the question, I read outside component, not totally outside of react

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer version of how to affect state on this [article](https://brettdewoody.com/accessing-component-methods-and-state-from-outside-react/) and it's [codepen](https://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/JprXEN) example.

It seems that this part of code

```
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.increment}>
        <div>Parent Value - {this.state.counter} - Click to increment</div>
        <ChildComponent ref={(childComponent) => {window.childComponent = childComponent}}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

does the trick.

We populate the `window` object with references of our child components - if we have - passing properties like `ref={(childComponent) => {window.childComponent = childComponent}`. Now `window.childComponent` access methods from the child component that can get/set the state.

The original codepen only attempts to read the state so I extended it to write too.
The trick is a new method

```
setStateExt = (state) => {
    this.setState(this.state = state);
  }
```

[see there](https://codepen.io/centurianii/pen/ZgvGoW).